# Highslide - unwanted background appears when mousing over around outside of expanded image

Tags: css, image, highslide

I'm having a problem with the expanded image in Highslide. For some reason, I'm getting some white/gray (#EBF6FF to be exact) background appearing when I bring the mouse close to the image around the outside. Here's a [link](http://www.autyfamily.net/HighslideScreenshot.png) to a screenshot.

It also does it on the sides (a white box/background appears, jutting out 13 pixels on either side, beginning at the bottom edge of the area shown in the image above), and the bottom, although for the bottom you need to mouseover outside the caption area, along the lower right and left corners of the image. The affected area is 13 pixels beyond the top and sides of the image. I've gone through my CSS and can't find any 13 pixel padding, and also can't find any references to #EBF6FF. Has anybody seen this before?

I've used Highslide in the past with the glossy dark border, but I wanted to switch to a borderless look. I'm not re-using any of the previous HS code (with the glossy border). I started this one from scratch using the latest version (4.1.13). Everything else is working fine, the only problem is with this unwanted background appearing on mouseover. Unfortunately, I'm still developing this on my localhost, so don't have it live to view on the web. But I can provide any code that you may need.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions anybody can provide!

Edit: This site isn't finished so I can't upload it yet, but [here's a link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQiAjv28H2I) to a video I took showing the issue.

Comment: This is hard to debug without a demo, but very easy with one.

Comment: Agreed. Need a live demo, or we'll just be taking wild guesses.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I was hoping the video would help. I'm not sure how I can upload the page and related documents (CSS, etc.), without breaking my existing site. I thought maybe if somebody saw the issue they may have experienced the same thing. I guess I may have to wait until I can complete the site overhaul and have uploaded everything.

Comment: It has all the earmarks of a CSS conflict, or perhaps something as simple as an unclosed anchor tag somewhere. With a live page, it will be a lot easier to track down. At least run your page through a validator - that might flag a trouble spot.

Comment: Just an update: I was playing with the CSS to fix a different issue, and somehow the one stated above got fixed in the process. I think it may have been in the HTML popups section. I'm also using Highslide to display YouTube videos, which uses the HTML popups CSS. I set a bunch of stuff to `display: none;` (header, footer, background, etc.) and that seemed to also fix this problem. It helped to go to the Highslide site and use the [Editor](http://highslide.com/editor/), taking a peek at the CSS while I was making changes.